# JavaScript popup url

Tags: javascript, web, popup

How can i get url of a popup opened by JS.
Here is my code:

```
var _url = 'someurlhere';
    var popupwindow = window.open(_url, "Popup", 'width=800, height=600');
    var _this = this;

    var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            console.log(popupwindow.document.URL);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    }, 500);
```

but I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'URL' of undefined` error on line with console.log(e.message). Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `popupwindow.location.href` instead `popupwindow.document.URL`

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because you are using a url that is a different domain than the page you are running the script on.  This is a violation of the "[same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)".  IOW it is XSS, not allowed.